# TS optional channing

Tags: typescript

`renderShimmers` is boolean or undefined. I want it to be `false` if it's `false` or `undefined`. Is there a simpler way than this?

```
this.props.renderShimmers ? this.props.renderShimmers : false
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any of these.

- `Boolean(this.props.renderShimmers)`
- `this.props.renderShimmers || false`
- `this.props.renderShimmers ?? false`
- `!!this.props.renderShimmers`

Comment: of these 4 id go with the first, its the easiest to read :)